# allocating vectors (or vectors of vectors) dynamically

Tags: c++, vector

I need to dynamically allocate 1-D and 2-D arrays whose sizes are given at run-time.

I managed to "discover" `std::vector` and I think it fits my purposes, but I would like to ask whether what I've written is correct and/or can be improved.

This is what I'm doing:

```
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector< std::vector<double> > matrix;

//... various code and other stuff

std::vector<double> *name = new std::vector<double> (size);
matrix *name2 = new matrix(sizeX, std::vector<double>(sizeY));
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Dynamically allocating arrays is required when your dimensions are given at runtime, as you've discovered.

However, `std::vector` is already a *wrapper* around this process, so dynamically allocating vectors is like a double positive. It's redundant.

Just write (C++98):

```
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector< std::vector<double> > matrix;
matrix name(sizeX, std::vector<double>(sizeY));
```

or (C++11 and later):

```
#include <vector>

using matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;
matrix name(sizeX, std::vector<double>(sizeY));
```

Answer (score 10):

You're conflating two issues, dynamic allocation and resizable containers. You don't need to worry about dynamic allocation, since your container does that for you already, so just say it like this:

```
matrix name(sizeX, std::vector<double>(sizeY));
```

This will make `name` an object with automatic storage duration, and you can access its members via `name[i][j]`.

Comment: First of all: thanks for the reply.
then, just to be totally sure I understood your answer, you mean that I do not need "new" with <vector>?

Comment: Short answer: Indeed, you do not. Medium answer: If you use C++ idiomatically, you should never be saying `new` anyway (with the possible exception of inside the constructor of a `unique_ptr`).

Comment: Ok, the medium answer is getting difficult for me, could you give me a reference?

Just to understand what do you mean by "idiomatically" or why I should not use `new`

Comment: Not sure about a reference, any modern, good C++ textbook I suppose... the point is that you shouldn't be managing resources manually, but rather always use a dedicated resource-managing container. If you have a concrete situation where you're tempted to say `new`, post it and ask how to do it better.

Comment: @Federico - It is not so much a "should not", but rather that you hardly ever *have to* use new and delete in C++ code. The library facilities, like std::vector and std::string, take care of this for you.

Comment: Why aren't the row vectors shared in this creation?

Comment: @NetMage: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you rephrase it please?

Comment: Never mind - I see the fill constructor is defined as making a copy of the initialization value, so `sizeX` copies of the vector will be used to fill out the array.

Answer (score 7):

What you're doing should basically work, *however*:

In general, *don't dynamically allocate objects*

If you want a vector, do this:

```
std::vector<double> vec(size);
```

not this:

```
std::vector<double>* vec = new std::vector<double>(size);
```

The latter gives you a pointer, which you have to delete. The former gives you a vector which, when it goes out of scope, cleans up after itself. (Internally, of course, it dynamically allocates objects, but the trick is that this is handled by the class itself, and you don't need to worry about it in your user code).

Comment: If you're running a single threaded application, sure. Multithreading introduces a whole new set of do's and don'ts when it comes to memory allocation.

Comment: @pg1989: are you suggesting that in multithreaded applications, you should try to have different threads perform allocation and deallocation? No, in a multithreaded program, the same rules apply, *only more so*.

Comment: No, I was more referring to concurrent access of shared resources. Perhaps I didn't phrase it right. It is true that in idiomatic c++ you should never explicitly call new. However, you still need to think about the objects you're manipulating as if you have, because if a thread tries to access an object that has already been destroyed, bad things can happen.

Comment: You need to think about ownership and lifetime, yes. That's always true, regardless of how many threads you have, and it has nothing to do with `new` and `delete`, and it's not unique to multithreading.

Comment: @jalf Suppose, I am implementing a `vector to vector` scenario basically a matrix with unknown rows and columns and I'm doing v[a].push_back(b) (`treating a & b as ints`). How should I declare the vector v without giving fixed length at compile-time? Because, directly writing `v[a].push_back(b)` is giving me `segmentation fault`?

Answer (score 2):

While the points the other answers made were very correct (don't dynamically allocate the vector via new, but rather let the vector do the allocation), if you are thinking terms of vectors and matrices (e.g. linear algebra), you might want to consider using the Eigen matrix library.

Answer (score 1):

You don't allocate containers dynamically. They can automatically manage memory for you if they themselves are not manually managed.

A vector grows when you add new items with `push_back` (or `insert`), you can choose its size from the start with arguments to the constructor, and you can resize it later with the `resize` method.

Creating a vector of vectors with your sizes with the constructor looks like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> > matrix(size, std::vector<double>(sizeY));
```

This means: `size` instances of a `std::vector<double>`, each containing `sizeY` doubles (initialized to 0.0).

Answer (score 1):

It is correct but could be made more efficient.

You could use the boost multidimensional arrays:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Or, you can implement your own class for it and handle the indexing yourself.
Perhaps something like this (which is not well tested):

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> >
class Array2d
{
public:
    typedef Array2d<T> self;
    typedef std::vector<T, A> Storage;

    typedef typename Storage::iterator       iterator;
    typedef typename Storage::const_iterator const_iterator;
    Array2d() : major_(0), minor_(0) {}
    Array2d(size_t major, size_t minor)
        : major_(major)
        , minor_(minor)
        , storage_(major * minor)
    {}

    template <typename U>
    Array2d(size_t major, size_t minor, U const& init)
        : major_(major)
        , minor_(minor)
        , storage_(major * minor, u)
    {
    }
    iterator begin()                { return storage_.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const    { return storage_.begin(); }
    iterator end()                  { return storage_.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const      { return storage_.end(); }
    iterator begin(size_t major) {
        assert(major < major_);
        return storage_.begin() + (major * minor_);
    }
    const_iterator begin(size_t major) const {
        assert(major < major_);
        return storage_.begin() + (major * minor_);
    }
    iterator end(size_t major) {
        assert(major < major_);
        return storage_.begin() + ((major + 1) * minor_);
    }
    const_iterator end(size_t major) const {
        assert(major < major_);
        return storage_.begin() + ((major + 1) * minor_);
    }
    void clear() {
        storage_.clear();
        major_ = 0;
        minor_ = 0;
    }
    void clearResize(size_t major, size_t minor)
    {
        clear();
        storage_.resize(major * minor);
        major_ = major;
        minor_ = minor;
    }
    void resize(size_t major, size_t minor)
    {
        if ((major != major_) && (minor != minor_))
        {
            Array2d tmp(major, minor);
            swap(tmp);

            // Get minimum minor axis
            size_t const dist = (tmp.minor_ < minor_) ? tmp.minor_ : minor_;
            size_t m = 0;
            // copy values across
            for (; (m < tmp.major_) && (m < major_); ++m) {
                std::copy(tmp.begin(m), tmp.begin(m) + dist, begin(m));
            }
        }
    }
    void swap(self& other)
    {
        storage_.swap(other.storage_);
        std::swap(major_, other.major_);
        std::swap(minor_, other.minor_);
    }
    size_t minor() const {
        return minor_;
    }
    size_t major() const {
        return major_;
    }
    T*       buffer()       { return &storage_[0]; }
    T const* buffer() const { return &storage_[0]; }
    bool empty() const {
        return storage_.empty();
    }
    template <typename ArrRef, typename Ref>
    class MajorProxy
    {
        ArrRef arr_;
        size_t major_;

    public:
        MajorProxy(ArrRef arr, size_t major)
        : arr_(arr)
        , major_(major)
        {}

        Ref operator[](size_t index) const {
            assert(index < arr_.minor());
            return *(arr_.buffer() + (index + (major_ * arr_.minor())));
        }
    };
    MajorProxy<self&, T&>
    operator[](size_t major) {
        return MajorProxy<self&, T&>(*this, major);
    }
    MajorProxy<self const&, T const&>
    operator[](size_t major) const {
        return MajorProxy<self&, T&>(*this, major);
    }
private:
    size_t major_;
    size_t minor_;
    Storage storage_;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you don't want to fill your stack and your memory requirement is large. Hence you may want to use vector> created dynamically especially while creating a table of a given row and col values.

Here is my take on this in C++11

```
int main() {
    int row, col;
    std::cin >> row >> col;
    auto *arr = new std::vector<std::vector<int>*>(row);
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
        auto *x = new std::vector<int>(col, 5);
        (*arr)[i] = x;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++) {
            std::cout << arr->at(i)->at(j) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include < iostream > 
 #include < vector >

 using namespace std;

int main(){

vector<int>*v = new vector<int>();   // for 1d vector just copy paste  it

v->push_back(5);
v->push_back(10);
v->push_back(20);
v->push_back(25);

for(int i=0;i<v->size();i++){
    cout<<v->at(i)<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;

delete v;

system("pause");
return 0;

     }
```

Answer (score -1):

**If you don't need to resize the array sizes at run time, then you can just use standard arrays (allocated at runtime)!**

However, if you do need to resize arrays at runtime, then you can use the following (revised) code:

```
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector< std::vector<double> > matrix;

//... various code and other stuff

std::vector<double> *name = new std::vector<double> (size);

matrix *name2 = new matrix(sizeX, std::vector<double>(sizeY));
```

In essence, all I've done is remove a single bracket (`(`).

Comment: yep, the braket was a typo, I removed it also from the original post :P