# Assigning vector sizes as array lengths

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-assignment

So I am currently working on a program in c++, and I want to make the following decleration:

```
methodOne()
{
    vector<int> one;
    vector<int> two;
... assigning to one and two...
    int a = one.size();
    int b = two.size();
    methodTwo(a, b);
}

methodTwo(int a, int b)
{
    int array[a][b];
}
```

When I attempt this, I get an error: a and b must be constant 
I have tried to assign a and b to const int a, const int b. However, that was no help. I was wondering if anyone knows how I can fix this kind of error.
 Thanks in advance for any help you are able to give!

Comment: Variable length arrays aren't standard c++.

Comment: It can't be easily "fixed", but you can change the array for something else, e.g. another vector.

Comment: What compiler means by "_a and b must be constant_" is that they need to be `constexpr` (i.e. known at compile time).

Answer (score 0):

An array's size must be known before the program runs. Its size is part its complete type, just like the element type itself.

You need something with a dynamic size instead. Use a `std::vector<int>` of size a * b:

```
methodTwo(int a, int b)
{
    std::vector<int> array(a * b);
}
```

You could also use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead, but why take all the trouble? After all, you can *access* the one-dimensional vector's elements as if it was two-dimensional data structure by calculating the offsets accordingly:

```
methodTwo(int a, int b)
{
    std::vector<int> array(a * b);
    // ...
    int x = 5;
    int y = 6;
    auto const element = array[y * a + x];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you already using vector so you can replace your array with

`typedef std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix;
matrix name(a, std::vector<int>(b));`

Comment: What advantage does this have over `std::vector<int> matrix(a * b)`? As I see it, it just causes some extra memory fragmentation and extra memory usage, because every row of the matrix requires a separate allocation and (usually) two extra pointers for size and capacity.

Comment: I follow it according to this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775643/allocating-vectors-or-vectors-of-vectors-dynamically?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: This answer doesn't address my reasoning at all.

Comment: Sorry for late replay 
I didn't see your answer before i post this and i think your way is better