# Why am I getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, stdvector

I am trying to print concentric rectangular pattern in a 2D matrix.

However, it shows me a segmentation fault. I tried making all the code as comment.

I figured the declaration itself has a fault. What is it ?

```
   int l = 2*A - 1; 
   vector<vector<int> > ar(l);

   for(int i = 0; i<(2*A - 1); i++)
   {
        for (int j = 0; j<(2*A - 1); j++)
        {
            int h= max(abs(A - i + 1),abs(A - j + 1));
            ar[i][j] = h+1;
        }

    }
    return ar;
```

Comment: You are using a vector of vector, but only allocate the outer one. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775643/allocating-vectors-or-vectors-of-vectors-dynamically) for correct allocation.

Comment: Instead of `ar[i][j] = h+1;`, try `ar.at(i).at(j) = h+1;`. The `at` member function performs bounds checking. Then, wrap it in a try block and catch exceptions.

Comment: You have declared `ar` to have a size incapable of holding any `int`s.  It's a `lx0` matrix.

Comment: The `vector<int>`s in the `vector<vector<int> >` are initialised with size zero.   All usage of `at[i][j]` in the inner loop therefore have undefined behaviour, since `operator[]()` does not resize a vector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [allocating vectors (or vectors of vectors) dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775643/allocating-vectors-or-vectors-of-vectors-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

> **I figured the declaration itself has a fault. What is it ?**

You are right. You have a two dimensional vector and you have only took cared of the single layer by declaring:

```
vector<vector<int> > ar(l);
```

Simple fix would be:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > ar(l, std::vector<int>(l));
```

This will now assure initializing the two dimensional vector array full of `0`S, with a size of `2*A - 1`.

See now: https://www.ideone.com/1wYCba

---

**Short Note**: However if you are really working on [concentric rectangular pattern](http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/3686/print-concentric-rectangular-pattern-in-a-2d-matrix), your code/ logic is wrong. Above code does not print what you want, even when now it complies.

Comment: Thank you so much. i got the mistake in logic too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while you created a vector with `2*A - 1` elements, each of these elements is an empty vector. So when you try to access elements of elements (two subscripts), you access something that does not exist.

One solution is to change those empty vectors to vectors with the assumed number of elements. Before starting your inner loop, add:

```
ar[i].resize(2*A - 1);
```

(If `A` is fixed, you may find `std::array` more convenient than vectors.)